# How to Join Multiple Arrays inside filter function of Arrays in Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am using Typescript in an Angular/Ionic project. I have an array of users that contain an array of skills. I have to filter users based on their online status as well as skills.

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Vikram Shah",
            "online_status": "Online",
            "skills": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "CSS"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "JavaScript"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "Python"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Abhay Singh",
            "online_status": "Online",
            "skills": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "HTML"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "CSS"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "JavaScript"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "Python"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Oberoi",
            "online_status": "Online",
            "skills": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "HTML"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "CSS"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "JavaScript"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "Python"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

This is how all skills look like

```
 this.skill_types = [
      {"id":8,"title":"Cleaner", checked:false},
      {"id":7,"title":"Painter", checked:false},
      {"id":6,"title":"Plumber", checked:false},
      {"id":5,"title":"Carpenter", checked:false},
      {"id":4,"title":"Advisor", checked:false},
      {"id":3,"title":"Team Leader", checked:false},
    {"id":2,"title":"Management", checked:false},
    {"id":1,"title":"Administrator", checked:false}
   ];
```

This array contains the IDs of skills that I want to filter

```
filterArr = [1, 3, 6];
```

This solution is almost working as expected. It is filtering well based on two criteria together.But not sure how to add condition for second filtering. The second filter should apply only if filterArr is not empty.

```
return this.items = this.items.filter((thisUser) => {
        return thisUser.online_status.toLowerCase().indexOf(onlineStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1 &&
       thisUser.skills.some(c => this.filterArr.includes(c.id))
      });
```

The issue I am facing with code above is When there is no skill selected in the filter criteria, I would like to display all users. But it is not working that way. The logic here is to not apply any filter when the size of selected skills (filter condition) is greater than zero. So I tried this way....which looks similar to the way above...but this makes everything worse.

```
  let filteredByStatus = [];
  filteredByStatus = this.items.filter((thisUser) => {
    return thisUser.online_status.toLowerCase().indexOf(onlineStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1
  });

  //Condition can be applied if filtering is separated
  let filteredBySkills = [];
  filteredBySkills = this.items.filter((thisUser) => {
    return thisUser.skills.some(c => this.filterArr.includes(c.id))
  });

  //Expecting to join results from multiple filters
  return this.items = filteredByStatus.concat(filteredBySkills);
```

But this is not working at all. Not sure what wrong is there. I am looking for a solution that enables to join arrays of similar objects without duplicating them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you need to join arrays for your filtering. You can use something like rxjs filter.

```
return from(this.items)
    .pipe(
      filter(user => {
        return user.online_status.toLowerCase().indexOf(onlineStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1 
                && user.skills.some(c => filterArr.includes(c.id));
      })
    );
```

Or if you like to split it up you can just change it to like:

```
return from(this.items)
    .pipe(
      filter(user => user.online_status.toLowerCase().indexOf(onlineStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1),
      filter(user => user.skills.some(c => filterArr.includes(c.id)))
    );
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pk3w8b

Comment: Okay. But how can I check if the array is not empty inside filter? That is my concern. I do not want the filtering to happen for Skills if there is an empty array and expect all users with different skills to appear in case of no skill filter.

Comment: @VishalKumar, you can use conditional statement: `filter(user => filterArr.length > 0 ? user.skills.some(c => filterArr.includes(c.id)) : true)`

Comment: This looks exactly something I probably need. Can you ellaborate this with answer. What does true mean here?

Comment: @VishalKumar, `filter` emit values that pass the provided condition. Anything evaluates true will emit values that based on the condition. So in this case, we want to return everything so we just return `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your condition a bit and place `!this.filterArr.length` in your condition (in terms of OR condition AND with user status) to make your whole condition gets true so that user gets filter.

Comment: (<your existing conditions >) || (<your first status condition>   && !this.filterArr.length)